# Rails habtm: select all that has at least one associated

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sections
end
```

I need to select all sections that has at least one associated post and order this sections by count of assotiated posts. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no opportunity to test this code, but it looks about right.

```
Section.select("sections.*, count(posts.id) AS post_count").
  joins(:posts).
  group("sections.id").
  order("post_count DESC")
```

Comment: Looks about right to me, I don't think you'll need the `having` though, seeing as it's an `INNER JOIN` it will only return `Section`s with at least one `Post`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Somehow I thought that this will produce outer join.

Comment: With having option I have an error that column post_count not exists. But without having it returns what I want. Thank you!

Comment: It prodices this query: SELECT sections.*, count(posts.id) AS post_count FROM "sections" INNER JOIN "posts_sections" ON "posts_sections"."section_id" = "sections"."id" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."id" = "posts_sections"."post_id" GROUP BY sections.id ORDER BY post_count DESC